# Grease pencil graph editor - no objects!

Tags: animation

[image: 1]The graph editor is just "dead". No entries appear. I do select them in the outliner. I am in object mode, there is just a blue horizontal line.  What am I missing? I've created a short animation that seems to work OK - just need to ease in/out a bit. Any help much appreciated by this newb - spent a lot of time  looking for the answer.

Comment: Could you please provide some more information? Does this problem appear with a certain blend file or is it a general problem with your blender configuration. Can you provide some screenshots and, if it's specific for a certain .blend-file, please upload it on https://blend-exchange.com/ and link it right here.

Comment: /Users/stuart/Desktop/Screenshot 2023-06-09 at 11.43.11 am.png Thanks Andre, it seems some files are  OK. Being a newb  I'm just missing something obvious... still trying to find how to upload the screen shot,Duh..

Comment: Thanks Andre - struggling a bit here with Posts etc...  I think you will see a screen shot now in the original post?  I did find an earlier blend file with the Graph editor showing an object - but some others don't.  Just missing a button somewhere? Or a misconception stuffing me up! Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: What were you expecting to see in the graph editor? just asking cos it only shows keyframes at the object level (like if you move/scale/rotate the GP object), but will not show drawn keyframes, those are only visible in the GP dopesheet as it's a totally separate animation system

Comment: OK !  Thanks pevinkinel -  I think I was expecting  moving to another keyframe and drawing another  pose would produce change in  L and R and S etc .So I'm off and running again, thank you.   but perhaps I should stick to doing some drawing or gardening..